# Programatically detect if an iOS device is supervised?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mdm

Is there a way to detect programatically if an iOS device is supervised.
MDM server can query the device about the supervision state, but is it possible to detect from an app?
Any help would be beneficial.

Comment: Nice idea, but seems there is no way to do so, AFAIK

Answer (score 0):

What's your use case for checking for supervision?  So far, there is no way for an application to check programmatically as there is no clear use case for it.  Supervision is used when trying to install profiles with payloads that require supervision or when trying to initiate autonomous single app mode from within an app.  In the former case, the MDM server can query supervision, as you've stated.  In the latter case of autonomous single app mode, you don't particularly care about supervision, you care about whether you were able to successfully get in or out of autonomous single app mode and the completion block allows you to check that (though you should probably have a message pop up to users if it fails to get you for the users to check that the device is supervised).

Would love to hear what the use case would be and if you have one, you may want to submit this as an enhancement request to Apple.